# I have a problem with my Title for my thesis

Tags: errors, unicode, input-encodings

```
not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.78 ... MEJORA DE EFICIENCIA  ̃EN SUS PROCESOS}}
                                                  \\[3em]
You may provide a definition with
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter 

[1
```

I already tried with

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You have only shown the end of the message, not the part which says which character is the problem. Do not use `[utf8x]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

MEJORA DE EFICIENCIA  ̃EN SUS PROCESOS

\end{document}
```

produces

```
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character ̃ (U+0303)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 MEJORA DE EFICIENCIA  ̃
                            EN SUS PROCESOS
?
```

showing the problem is the ~. You only showed the last part of the message.

It is better to avoid combining characters, but here you have ~ combining with a space, so I'm not sure what is intended. If you delete it, it runs without error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

MEJORA DE EFICIENCIA EN SUS PROCESOS

\end{document}
```